# Retrieve URL JSON data in MS Access

Tags: json, ms-access

There is a web service that allows me to go to a URL, with my API-key, and request a page of data.  The data is returned as JSON.  The JSON is well-formed, I ran it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and confirmed its OK.

What I would like to do is retrieve the JSON data from *within* MS Access (2003 or 2007), if possible, and build a table from that data (first time thru), then append/update the table on subsequent calls to that URL.   I would settle for "pre-step" where I retrieve this information via another means.  Since I have an API key in the URL, I do not want to do this server-side.  I would like to keep it all within Access, run it on my PC at home (its for personal use anyway).

If I have to use another step before the database load then Javascript?  But I dont know that very well.  I dont even really know what JSON is other than what I have read in Wikipedia. The URL looks similar to:

```
http://www.SomeWebService.com/MyAPIKey?p=1&s=50
```

**where:** p = page number
       s = records per page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access DB is a JavaScript Lib for MS Access, quick page search says they play nicely with JSON, and you can input/output with. boo-ya.

http://www.accessdb.org/

EDIT:
dead url; wayback machine ftw:
http://web.archive.org/web/20131007143335/http://www.accessdb.org/

also sourceforge
http://sourceforge.net/projects/accessdb/

Comment: cant vote you up because I need 15 pts.  you got my +1 though.

Comment: link appears to be dead, quick search did not seem to find a new location

Comment: the wayback machine is your friend:  http://web.archive.org/web/20131007143335/http://www.accessdb.org/